# Why does this experiment not show how fast a reference frame is moving?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

An observer on a train has a light pulse generator on the floor and a mirror on the ceiling. The time a light pulse takes to travel from the generator and back again can be measured. The observer thinks he is seeing

[image: this].

In fact he is seeing this

[image: this]

The ray which was going vertically up actually hit the train ceiling a ways back. The ray which he saw was the one which was traveling obliquely. So now imagine I have a prism in front of the light pulse generator that splits the light into a fan of colors. You angle the prism so that the red light (which refracts the least) goes straight up to the train car ceiling. The blue light (which is refracted more) angles away (like in the drawing). So now I should be able to calculate the velocity of my inertial frame (the train car) by looking at what color light I get at my detector.

Relativity says that my experimental results should be the same in an inertial frame of reference regardless of velocity. But I cannot reconcile this experiment with that fact. I cannot derive the Lorentz transformation from it.

EDIT: After reading and rereading all the comments and answers, I pared my question down to its 'bare bones' and realized I was not asking the right question. I have restated the fundamental issue of my question in another form here:

[How feasible is it to measure the trajectory of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/675044/how-feasible-is-it-to-measure-the-trajectory-of-light)

Comment: The fact that you write "The observer thinks he is seeing" and "In fact he is seeing" means you have missed the point of relativity completely. "In fact" in both cases he is hurling through space at blazing speeds relative to the centre of the galaxy. There is no "stationary" observer.

Comment: there are no 'two cases'. You misunderstand my statement. The moving observer ONLY sees the diagonal pulse. His measurement of time is correct. However his measurement of the distance travelled is erroneous if he only measures the height of the ceiling. The experiment I outlined should show a spectral shift of the received light vs velocity. So even tho the observer does not know he is moving, he should be able to calculate his velocity from the spectral shift. Perhaps I confused you by adding the 'stationary observer' in the last sentence so I removed it.

Comment: @aquagremlin The moving observer's distance measurement is exactly correct in his own reference frame. In his frame of reference, the light pulse travels at *c* up and down to cover the distance from floor to ceiling and back. To say that his measurement of the distance is "erroneous" suggests that the light actually travels farther than that, therefore moving a a *speed higher than c*, which is impossible. There is no one "correct" measurement of distance traveled, different observers will measure the distance (and time) differently.

Comment: The observer only measures 'rest distance'. The light ray reveals to him that he was misinformed. Like the consummate magician she is, nature deceived the observer into thinking he was seeing something when in fact he was seeing something else.

Comment: @ Marius Ladegård Meyer
  regardless of my velocity through the galaxy, if I add more velocity then it should be detectable with the method above.

Comment: I don't understand your diagram. Where is the mirror located in the train? If the entire ceiling of the train is a mirror, the observer on the train sees red light incident on the ground at the position of the light source and blue light incident on the ground some distance away. I don't even see how relativity enters the picture.

Comment: Re the phrase "if I add more velocity" (currently two comments above):  Any time you change your velocity, you are increasing it in some frames and decreasing it in others.  There is no such thing as "increasing your velocity" in any absolute sense.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a prism in front of the light pulse generator that splits the light into a fan of colors. You angle the prism so that the red light (which refracts the least) goes straight up to the train car ceiling. The blue light (which is refracted more) angles away (like in the drawing). So now I should be able to calculate the velocity of my inertial frame (the train car) by looking at what color light I get at my detector.

This analysis neglects relativistic aberration.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_aberration

When you account for the relativistic aberration you find that it is the same light color which is detected in all frames, regardless of the speed. As such it cannot detect the velocity of the inertial frame.

Comment: Thank you for the reference but it seems to be saying something different. It states "Suppose, in the reference frame of the observer, the source is moving with speed v at an angle θ relative to the vector from the observer" In my construct. the source (the light pulse generator) and the observer are moving in the same direction.  Perhaps a different construct would illustrate what I am trying to say but pictures dont fit in this comment. Imagine a red laser pointing vertically. Imagine a blue laser angled away. They both fire concurrently. A stationary train will show a red reflection.

Comment: A blue light will be detected if the train is moving fast enough (depending on the angle of the blue laser)

Comment: The observers are irrelevant. They are just verbal short hand for the reference frame. You have two frames. According to the relativistic aberration formula in one frame the red light is vertical and in the other frame the red light is angled.

Comment: I am not speaking of two frames. There is only one frame. The moving train. Light travels in straight lines so only the blue light can be reflected.

Comment: There are always an infinite number of frames. Here there are two of interest. The one where the train is moving and the one where it is at rest. If the reflected light is red in one frame it is red in both. If it is blue in one frame it is blue in both. As shown by the aberration formula that you seem determined to ignore. But whatever, I am sure that deliberately ignoring a common relativistic effect means that you have found a valid loophole that nobody else noticed in more than a century

Answer (score 0):

Your question is based on several misunderstandings.

Firstly, it is impossible to calculate any velocity (either in SR or in non-relativistic physics) without specifying a reference frame with respect to which movements are measured. Since you only mention the rest frame of the train, in which the velocity of the train is zero, it is impossible to calculate any other velocity.

The train is stationary in its own frame of reference. What is observed in the carriage is light obeying the normal laws of reflection. You are quite wrong to say that 'in fact' the observer on the train sees light moving on an angled path. In fact, a ray of light which travels vertically upwards in the frame of the carriage will be reflected back down vertically to the emitter- it is only in other frames moving relative to the train that such a ray will follow an angled path, and the size of the angle will vary from frame to frame according to each frame's speed relative to the carriage.

Passing light through a prism is no different, for the purpose of this discussion, to having a light source that simply emits rays in all directions. The path of any individual ray will depend upon the angle at which it hits the mirrored ceiling.

If the detector is in the same horizontal position as the source, the detector will detect whatever rays are emitted vertically upwards. If you use a prism angled so that only the red light heads off vertically, then the detector will always receive the red light, as the red light will always bounce normally off the mirror directly above and return to the floor directly below. The other colours will hit the mirror at an angle and return to the floor further along the carriage.