# How feasible is it to measure the trajectory of light?

Tags: speed-of-light

Consider an apparatus in a stationary vehicle

A very brief laser pulse is emitted. I depict the pulse in the drawing below at three different times, t1,t2,t3. The pulse travels and a measurement would show the laser pulse hitting the tape measure at a specific point on the ceiling of the vehicle. The tape measure is lit up at '6'.

[image]

Now get the vehicle up to a new speed and repeat the experiment.

At t1,

[image]

At t2,

[image]

At t3,

[image]

The tape measure is lit up at '1'.

The problem I have with making an experiment like this is the initial calibration. The first image implies the vehicle is stationary. But the solar system is whipping through the galaxy at 220 km/sec. Since c= 3oo,ooo km/sec, we are already at 0.00073 c. So to 'zero out' my 'stationary' measurement, the laser has to be tipped a little in a certain direction.  Then I have to change the vehicular velocity by a certain minimum amount to be able to detect a change.

If the tape measure is 3 meters away from the emitter, light will make the journey in 10^-8 seconds. If I increased my speed by 100 meters/second, then vehicle will travel 10^-6 meters between emission and detection of the pulse. So, the repeat experiment should show the laser dot 1 micron away from the initial measurement.

It seems I should be able to use this method to calculate the change of my speed through space even though at both times the experiment is performed, there is no acceleration and both states are 'inertial reference frames'.

EDIT: ALL comments and answers in the past 2 days have referred to theory of SR and basically say that the experiment will always show the laser hitting the tape measure at the 6 mark. Please note that I am NOT saying that the absolute velocity of any moving inertial frame can be measured. Rather , I am saying that the change of velocity of a moving inertial frame can be detected BECAUSE light velocity is constant in all frames. All the remarks about tossing a ball in a moving frame refer to Galilean relativity where velocity is additive.

Also, I am not making ANY references to time. In this simple experiment there is no stationary observer with a stopwatch. This is not about Lorentz contraction.

If light were to always impact at the '6' mark, that implies that the changing the velocity of the train could affect the velocity of light.

It's a simple enough experiment to do on the next trip to Mars and will keep the passengers from getting bored. How bout it Elon?

Comment: Next time you are in a train, or a bus driving smoothly, try tossing a small ball up into the air and catching it again. Do you find that the ball whips back over your head and hits the back of the bus?

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: why should light behave like a ball?

Comment: "the laser has to be tipped a little in a certain direction." - no, it doesn't.

Comment: @ProfRob -  the initial calibration requires tipping the laser some way to get the light to hit the mark.

Comment: It does not. Your thought experiment takes a premise that is _experimentally_ shown to be incorrect, and follows it to an incorrect conclusion.

Comment: "It seems I should be able to use this method to calculate the change of my speed through space even though at both times the experiment is performed, there is no acceleration and both states are 'inertial reference frames'." which should first cause you to worry that the premise of your question is incorrect...

Comment: You say 'if light were to always impact at the '6' mark, that implies that the changing the velocity of the train could affect the velocity of light.' Why do you think that to be the case?

Answer (score 4):

Your scenario descriptions do not match reality.  If the geometry of the laser and the train remain the same, then the beam hits the same spot at all speeds.

It will change if the car's *acceleration* changes.

In fact, this is the same if you toss a ball in the air.  It too starts with the same horizontal velocity as the car and keeps it throughout the toss.  A perfect toss will hit the same spot on the ceiling at any non-accelerating speed for the car.

Comment: Why should light behave like a ball?

Comment: There are many cases where it may not, but this is an analogy to give a familiar reference for what is happening.  In this case both the ball and the light source have non-zero momentum.  All the interactions that exchange/conserve momentum with the rest of the system apply to both.

Comment: If the horizontal motion of the train car could add to the vertical velocity of light, then the velocity and momentum of light would increase as would that of a ball. But it cannot for light. Therefore light cannot behave like a ball.

Comment: The analogy isn't perfect.  But you can calculate the horizontal momentum of the system in both cases.  If the light were to go "straight up" in both cases, then we ask why the there is no momentum transfer for the stationary train and there is for the rolling one.

Answer (score 0):

If you aim the light to hit the point '6' then it will do so regardless of the speed of the train (assuming the emitter moves with the train).

You must not confuse the speed of light, which is constant, with the direction of it. Suppose you sit on a train and shine a laser directly up at a spot on the ceiling. Now imagine that you are observed by n different observers each passing you at a different speed- their motion relative to you does not make the spot move. The light follows the line in which you have directed it, which is a vertical path in the carriage. In every other frame moving relative to the carriage, the light follows an angled trajectory, the start point of which is the laser in your hand and the end point of which is the same spot on the ceiling. If your tape measure was attached to a ceiling on the platform, then the light moving up vertically in the carriage frame would follow an angled path in the platform frame and hit a point other than '6', but if the tape measure is moving with the carriage then the light will always hit the same point on it.

Suppose you are sitting in a stationary carriage with a glass roof. You hold a laser pointer in your hand. Directly above you a small black cross is painted on the glass roof. The carriage is parked immediately under a tape measure stretching along the track (ie with the tape almost brushing against the upper surface of the glass). You are directly under the point '1' on the tape measure, so that if you flash the laser vertically upwards at the black cross, the shadow of the cross appears at the point '1' on the tape measure. Now suppose you repeat the process but with the train moving: just as you pass under the point '1' on the tape measure, you again flash the laser vertically upwards. By the time the light from the laser has reached the ceiling, the carriage will have moved down the track somewhat, so instead of the shadow of the cross hitting the point '1' on the tape, it hits a point further down the length of the tape. If you repeat the experiment at successively higher speeds, each time flashing the laser vertically upwards on the carriage as you pass under the point '1' on the tape, the shadow will appear progressively further down the tape. In the frame of the platform, the light takes an angled path, staring directly below the point '1' on the tape and ending at some point further down the tape. In the frame of the carriage, the end point of the trajectory, ie the point upon the tape where the light impinges upon it, is also the position of the black cross, so in the frame of the carriage the path of the light is always vertical.

Comment: although I respect your adherence to dogma, your statement is not illuminating

Comment: I have now shone more light, if you will excuse the weak pun, on the subject.

Comment: To  use your construct where the tape measure is on the platform, then imagine a bunch of trains with different speeds pulsing a laser as they pass by the mark. In all cases, the lasers will always hit the mark. The speed of the train has no impact on the speed or direction of the light.

Comment: Please see my second addendum

Answer (score 0):

To get a directional beam of light you need to "funnel" the light in that direction somehow, and however you do that, the beam will move diagonally when the train is moving, at just such an angle that it always hits the same spot on the ceiling.

That follows immediately from the principle of relativity, but you can analyze specific setups just for fun.

For example, you could put a light bulb in an opaque box that's painted black on the inside, and make a small hole in the box that's far enough from the bulb that the bulb can only be seen through it from a narrow range of viewing angles. When the box moves to the right, the hole will have moved to the right of the bulb by the time light from the bulb reaches it, so the light that makes it through the hole will be angled to the right.

Comment: the laser is collimated. no 'angled' light exists.

Comment: @aquagremlin Analyzing a laser in a moving frame would be pretty difficult, but you could imagine, e.g., a tube containing particles that bounce back and forth between the ends, and occasionally escape through one end. Their paths are diagonal with respect to the reference frame since the tube moves sideways.

Answer (score 0):

If the velocity of the train is in the $x$-direction, and $y$ is vertical, with the laser in the train frame shooting straight up. A vertically propagating light wave is described by:

$$ E(x', y', t') = E_0e^{i\phi(x',y',t')}$$

where the phase is:

$$ \phi(x', y', t') = \vec k' \cdot \vec x'-\omega' t' = k'_yy'-\omega t$$

where $(x',y',t')$ are the coordinates in the moving (primed) frame,

$$ k'_{\mu} = (0,k'_y, \omega'/c) $$

is the 4-wave vector (with $\omega'=k'c$).

Imagine the line of 0-phase as it is emitted from the laser aperture at $y=0$ at time $t'=0$. It solves:

$$ 0 = k'_yy'-\omega't'= -k'_y0-\omega'0=0$$

Pretty straight forward. At a fixed point in time, lines of constant phase are parallel to the $y'$ axis.

Now boost that into the stationary frame where $t$ becomes a function of both $t'$ and $x'$, and see if a line of constant phase is parallel to the $y$-axis.

Comment: I am not talking about phase.

Answer (score 0):

It is a postulate of special relativity that

> the laws of physics are the same in all inertial frames of reference

This means that it is impossible to distinguish  which of the two trains is in motion.  If the pulse really hit a different number when travelling at different speeds the postulate would be violated.

That wouldn't happen as special relativity has been carefully checked for over a century and found to be valid.

Comment: There is only one train. There is only one observer. This is not about simultaneity.

Comment: @   aquagremlin 'two trains' was shorthand for 'the train as shown in the top diagram or the train 'in motion' represented by the bottom three diagrams'.  The answer as not about  simultaneity.